# How can I save NSView's content to the file larger than it is

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview

I have NSView 300x300px but I need that my NSView's content image would be 1000x1000px saved to file. Is it possible? I don't want to change size of NSView it's just for saving.

So far I have this:

```
NSImage *viewImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[self dataWithPDFInsideRect:[self bounds]]];

[[viewImage TIFFRepresentation] writeToFile:@"..." atomically:YES];
```

It's working fine for saving 300x300px image (View's size), but how to make 1000x1000px with View's content same as 300x300 just larger 1000x1000px output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create a new image of the desired size](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/initWithSize%3a), [lock focus on it](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/lockFocus), [scale](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAffineTransform_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAffineTransform/scaleBy%3a) by (the desired size ÷ the view's size) (taking aspect ratios into account, unless you don't mind stretching the content), [tell the view to draw](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/drawRect%3a) everything in [the view's bounds](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/bounds), [unlock focus](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/unlockFocus) on the image, and save the image.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, maybe you can write some sample code how to achieve this. I know how to lock and unlockFocus works but it's hard to understand for me how to do everything else, sorry :(

Comment: @Tom: I've added documentation links.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm having problems with scaling.. Maybe You can explain it more? I have created like this: NSAffineTransform *at = [NSAffineTransform transform];
     float heightFactor = 1000/[self bounds].size.height;
     float widthFactor = 1000/[self bounds].size.width;
     float scale;
     if(heightFactor > widthFactor){
     scale = widthFactor;
     } else {
     scale = heightFactor;
     }
     
     [at scaleBy:scale]; what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Tom: Did you concatenate the transform after you finished setting it up? If you don't, you've set it up for nothing. (By the way: The correct type is `CGFloat`, not `float`, and you really should create variables for your desired width and height instead of hard-coding `1000` for each.)

Answer (score 0):

you could try that,

Assuming you would like to save NSImage to file,

```
// it will save in the user document folder 
+(NSString *)writeImageToFile:(NSImage *)pImage FileName:(NSString *)pFileName{

    // Make the Complete File name 
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    // yes it should be in the user document folder by default 
    NSString *pCompleteFileName = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:pFileName];

    // now we can save the same 
    [[pImage TIFFRepresentation] writeToFile:pCompleteFileName atomically:YES];

    return pCompleteFileName;


}
```